# AngularJS - Passing parameter to URL

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-material

i have here an app that has a list of messages.

[image: screenshot1]

Now, for me to read the messages. Each message must have a different ID.
My problem is, how do I put parameter in the URL for the message have a unique identifier.

[image]

I am using angularjs and ionic framework.

Comment: https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng1/hellosolarsystem#state-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost:8100/#/user/read/messageId

- In you ui-router state declaration,, in the url section, set url: '/read/{messageId}'
- In the resolve block of that state, use $stateParams.messageId

example: https://rclayton.silvrback.com/passing-state-via-routes

Comment: can I use $location.path('url' + param) ?